# How to define a Ruby Struct which accepts its initialization arguments as a hash?

Tags: ruby

I have a situation where I would like to create a class which accepts many arguments and has setters and getters in the fewest lines of code possible (for maintainability). I thought that using a Struct would be a good idea for this:

```
Customer = Struct.new(:id, :username, :first_name, :last_name, :address1, ...etc...)

Customer.new(123, 'joe', 'Joe', ...etc...)
```

However, I don't like having to know the exact order of the attributes. I prefer Ruby 2's keyword arguments feature:

```
class Customer
  attr_accessor :id, :username, :first_name, ...etc...
  def initialize(id:, username:, first_name:, last_name:, address1:, ...etc...)
    @id = id
    @username = username
    @first_name = first_name
    ...etc...
  end
end

Customer.new(id: 123, username: 'joe', first_name: 'Joe', ...etc...)
```

However, writing this all out requires a lot more code and is more tedious. Is there a way to achieve the same thing in a short-hand like the Struct?

Comment: Just as a thought, you might prefer an OpenStruct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cant you just do:

```
def initialize(hash)
  hash.each do |key, value|
    send("#{key}=", value)
  end
end
```

UPDATE:

To specify default values you can do:

```
def initialize(hash)
  default_values = {
    first_name: ''
  }
  default_values.merge(hash).each do |key, value|
    send("#{key}=", value)
  end
end
```

If you want to specify that given attribute is required, but has no default value you can do:

```
def initialize(hash)
  requried_keys = [:id, :username]
  default_values = {
    first_name: ''
  }
  raise 'Required param missing' unless (required_keys - hash.keys).empty?
  default_values.merge(hash).each do |key, value|
    send("#{key}=", value)
  end
end
```

Comment: One drawback is that you don't get required keywords.

Comment: I think it's **dangerous** to send all keys of the hash as methods using `send`. Use at least `public_send` (which refuses to send to private methods) or validate they keys against a list of allowed attributes.

Comment: If you want to avoid using `send`, you could just use `self[key] = value`

Comment: I found myself doing this in every project I worked on, so wrote a gem (https://github.com/rohitpaulk/named_struct) that makes this easier. It defines a `NamedStruct` class that inherits from Struct, and only changes the initialization behavior.

Comment: In addition, you can also call your constructor like this: `def initialize(*args) super(*args) end` that way you avoid the side-affects of named parameters.

Answer (score 34):

In ruby 2.5 you can do the following:

```
Customer = Struct.new(
  :id, 
  :username,
  :first_name, 
  keyword_init: true
)

Customer.new(username: "al1ce", first_name: "alice", id: 123)
=> #<struct Customer id=123, username="al1ce", first_name="alice">
```

references:

- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Struct.html

Comment: I've been waiting for this.

Answer (score 7):

---

If you don't care about performance, you can use an `OpenStruct`.

```
require 'ostruct'

user = OpenStruct.new(id: 1, username: 'joe', first_name: 'Joe', ...)
user.first_name

=> "Joe"
```

See [this](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) for more details.

---

It's entirely possible to make it a class and define methods on it:

```
class Customer < Openstruct
  def hello
    "world"
  end
end

joe = Customer.new(id: 1, username: 'joe', first_name: 'Joe', ...)
joe.hello

=> "world"
```

But again, because OpenStructs are implemented using `method_missing` and `define_method`, they are pretty slow. I would go with BroiSatse's answer. If you care about required parameters, you should so something along the lines of

```
def initialize(params = {})   
    if missing_required_param?(params)
      raise ArgumentError.new("Missing required parameter")   
    end   
    params.each do |k,v|
      send("#{k}=", v)   
    end 
end

def missing_required_params?(params)
  ...
end
```

Comment: That's neat, didn't know this. :)

Comment: This is close to what I want, but can you also make it a class and define methods on it?

Answer (score 3):

In addition, you can rely on the constructor of `Struct` itself.

```rb
def initialize(*args)
  super(*args)
  # put your magic here!
end
```

This way you avoid the side-affects of named parameters etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Struct and reduce the amount of code to a minimum by adding a factory method (called build here) and if necessary a validate method to your struct

```
Struct.new("Example",:a,:b) do
    def build(a:, b:nil)
        s = Struct::Example.new(a,b)
        s.validate
        return s
    end
    def validate
        unless a == 'stuff' || a == 'nonsense'
            raise ValidationError, "broken"
        end
    end
 end

 m = Struct.Example.build(a: 'stuff')
```

where validate is intended to so something like check strings have certain values, rather than just relying on the required parameters check.

Now you only have to remember the order once, when you write the build method

Answer (score 1):

Variation on the theme, but a bit more refined, works in any ruby

```
class Struct
  module HashConstructable
    def from_hash hash
      rv = new
      hash.each do |k, v|
        rv.send("#{k}=", v)
      end
      rv
    end
    # alias_method :[], :from_hash
  end
end
```

and then

```
class MyStruct < Struct.new(:foo, :boo)
  extend Struct::HashConstructable
end
```

and you have best of both worlds this way - no funny name clashes and side-effects and it's clear want you want to do when you do it:

```
MyStruct.from_hash(foo: 'foo')
```

does exactly what you think it does. With a bit more possible side-effects but nicer syntax you can add the `alias_method :[], :from_hash` part, this allows you:

```
MyStruct[foo: 'foo']
```

this is also nice because it reminds (me) of the `Hash[]` constructor which creates a hash out of something that isn't hash.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach you could use.

```
class A
  def initialize(h)
    h.each do |k, v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
      create_method("#{k}=") { |v|instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v ) }
      create_method("#{k}")  { instance_variable_get("@#{k}") }
    end 
  end
end    

def create_method(name, &block)
  self.class.send(:define_method, name, &block)
end

a = A.new(apple: 1, orange: 2)
a.apple     #=> 1
a.apple = 3
a.apple     #=> 3
a.orange    #=> 2
```

`create_method` is straight from the documentation for [Module#define_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method).